# how to set nginx location for any subfolders

Tags: nginx, location

I want to set root path not need password, all subfolder needs password. How to write the conf.

```
location / {  #root not need password
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex_localtime on;
    autoindex_format html;
    charset utf-8,gbk;
    }
location ~ ^/*  {  # all subfolder need password
    auth_basic           "please input password";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/nginx/passwd;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to match a URI with more than one `/`, use `location ~ ./`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
location ~ /[^/]*$ {  # this one will match only root folder
    ...
}
location / {  # this one will match any other folder
    ...
}
```

Regex locations have greater priority than prefix ones, so first regex locations will overtake any request for the root folder or some file inside it. Second location will be used for any other request.

You can move all your `autoindex_...` and `charset` directives to the `server` context if both locations should share the same settings. Otherwise you'll need to duplicate them for both locations.